# i have installed xampp on ubuntu 18.04 .. but why is an error like this?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm a beginner.
I have installed Xampp on ubuntu 18.04.
Apache web server and proFTPD are running and the lights are green
why can't mysql run ??
I clicked Start, but it still hasn't run

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

"invalid settings".

That means you need to check host, user name and password set in phpmyadmin and compare it to what you set in mysql.

Comment: how do I check the host ??